# What is better: select date with trunc date or between

Tags: mysql

I need to create a query to select some data of my mysql db based on date, but in my where clause i have to options:

1 - trunc the date:

```
select count(*) from mailing_user where date_format(create_date, '%Y-%m-%d')='2013-11-05';
```

2 - use between

```
select count(*) from mailing_user where create_date between '2013-11-05 00:00:00' and '2013-11-05 23:59:59';
```

the two query's will work, but whats the better? Or, what's recommended? Why?

Comment: IMO the second query performs faster than the first one if the column is indexed, untested though.

Comment: what is the type of the date column?  is it `DATETIME`?

Comment: @Slowcoder yes.... its DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article to read.

http://willem.stuursma.name/2009/01/09/mysql-performance-with-date-functions/

If your created_date column is indexed, the 2nd query will be faster.

But if the column is not indexed and if this is your defined date format, you can use the following query.

```
select count(*) from mailing_user where DATE(create_date) = '2013-11-05';
```

I use `DATE` instead of `DATE_FORMAT` as I can make use of the native feature of getting in this format('2013-11-05').

Comment: @Elvis Oliveira, whenever you try to apply a function to an column that may be in the index, you basically are making the index useless.  Between is better.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you want to select **records from one day**, according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) `A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision.`

So this means your second query might actually get unlucky and miss some records that were inserted into the table at the very last second of that day, so that is why I would say the first one is more precise and is guaranteed to always get you the correct result.

The downside of this is that you cannot index that column using the `date_format`-function, because MySQL isn't cool with that.

If you don't want to use `date_format` and get around the precision issue you would change

`where create_date between '2013-11-05 00:00:00' and '2013-11-05 23:59:59'`

into

`where create_date >= '2013-11-05 00:00:00' and create_date < '2013-12-05 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 will be faster if you have an index on the create_date because number one won't be able to use the index to quickly scan the results.
However this requires there to be an index on the create_date.

Otherwise I imagine they would be similar speed, possibly the second would still be faster because of the smaller processing time to compare(datetime comparison rather than converting to a string and comparing strings), but I doubt it'd be significant.